Open Client side puppeteer browser from AWS server
I'm currently working on a project hosted on an AWS server, and I have a specific requirement: when a user clicks on a button within my project's page, I want to open a website using Puppeteer. Since my project is hosted on a server, clicking on the button triggers an API call to open the browser, but the browser window not be displayed to the user. (project is developed in node js)
Additionally, I'm looking for guidance on how to launch the browser window on the client's browser (front-end) after the button click.
I'm seeking advice or a solution on how to achieve this functionality seamlessly within my project. Any insights or suggestions on how to implement this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

This is basically impossible--a browser can't open an automated browser on the client on button click for obvious security reasons. Puppeteer doesn't run on the client side. Can you provide context for why you want to do this? There may be a better way to achieve whatever you're trying to achieve.

Does this answer your question? How to make Puppeteer work with a ReactJS application on the client-side
